# Incorrect image size when generating raster png images from vector data

Tags: gis, openlayers, gdal, geoserver, wms

I am writing a python API (WMS format) to fetch the gridded weather data(rainfall) and convert it into png images. I am using GDAL for this and involves below steps:

1. Fetching data from database using the BBOX from WMS
2. Rasterizing the data using **gdal.Rasterize** and converting the data into tiff files
3. Then applying style to the tiff using **gdal.DEMProcessing** and converting the tiff into png and returning the PNG images as output from the API.
4. Consuming this WMS API from openlayers to overlay the data on map.

**Problem:**
The problem I am facing is I am unable to get proper image size of the generated images because of which the data is shown as below in the image. Need help to know what is the correct set of options to be used in rasterize  or demprocessing to get correct output. Sample code:

```
options = gdal.RasterizeOptions(
                format='GTiff', attribute='value', noData=NoData_value,
                width=w, height=h,
                outputType=gdalconst.GDT_Float32,
                outputBounds=[x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max],
                outputSRS=crs)
```

[image: WMS Image on map]

Comment: why not just request PNG tiles from GeoServer?

Comment: @IanTurton, As mentioned, it is custom API of WMS specification

Comment: Very strange way of doing it, why do you need to rasterize and use DEM?
Why don't you simply directly create a raster GeoTIFF with the data coming from the database?

Comment: @mmomtchev, how to convert precipitation data directly into coloured GeoTiff, can you provide any sample code?

Comment: What form does have your original data? rows and columns with floating point numbers?

Comment: lat, long with floating point numbers fetched as a dataframe --> saved as csv,vrt --> rasterized to tiff --> applied color map using demprocessing --> converted to PNG using translate